# Why is my learning curve always at 100% while my validation curve increases with training samples?

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest, validation

I am relatively new to machine learning  and have the following problem:

I have built a random forest model which works relatively well and now I am trying to interpret the results.

The learning curve looks like this:

[image]

Now my question: How can it be that the training accuracy is always 1?

The code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores =\
    learning_curve(estimator = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100), X = X_train, y = y_train, train_sizes = np.linspace(0.1,1,5), cv  = 5, n_jobs = -1)

train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)

plt.plot(train_sizes, train_mean,
         color = "blue", marker = 'o',
         markersize = 5,label  ='Training accuracy')

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, 
                 train_mean + train_std, 
                 train_mean - train_std,
                 alpha=0.15, color = 'blue')

plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, 
         color='red', linestyle = '--',
         marker = 's',markersize = 5, 
         label = 'Validation accuracy')

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, 
                 test_mean + test_std, 
                 test_mean - test_std,
                 alpha=0.15, color = 'green')
    

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Number of training examples')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.ylim([0.25, 1.01])
plt.show
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can it be that the training accuracy is always 1?

That's by construction of the decision trees in the RF: (at least by default) the trees are not pruned. Thus roughly 2/3 (more precisely, approximately 1 - 1/e) of the trees will contain the training case and can look up the correct solution. Even if the 1/e trees which were not trained with this case would always predict wrongly, they'd always be outvoted.

Conclusion: for RF, only oob error i.e. using only those trees that were not trained on the case or validation/vreification with proper unknown cases are relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer!

Comment: Now I've changed the max_depth to 15, and this finally changes the training curve. Now I  have nearly no variance but I have higher bias (acc score ~ 68% for validation). Is this the right way to improve the forest? Because, If I'm testing the forest with no regulation of max_depth, i get a better accuracy score with the test set...
So I am guessing that for my problem a overfitting model isn't that bad?

Comment: No, overfitting of the individual trees in the random forest is not a problem. You need to seriously read up on ensemble models, bagging and random forests, they follow a very different approach compared to many other models. Understanding these concepts is key to understanding what hyperparameters to tune for which reasons and how. E.g. there is no optimal number of trees in the sense that e.g. a model complexity hyperparameter will be optimal for a non-aggregating model.